# How to loop the audio file: play again after it ends javax.sound.sampled

Tags: java, javasound

I'm trying to play a sound over and over. I have this code:

```
public void play()  {
        try  {
            URL defaultSound = getClass().getResource(filename);
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream =
                    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultSound);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start( );
            System.out.println(clip.getMicrosecondLength());
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
            clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
                @Override
                public void update(LineEvent event) {
                    try {
                        clip.start();
                        Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)  {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but it only plays the sound once.

Answer (score 1):

```
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start( );
```

Should be:

```
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); // <- NEW!
clip.start( );
```

See [`Clip.loop(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop(int)):

> **Parameters:**
> `count` - the number of times playback should loop back from the loop's end position to the loop's start position, or `LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY` to indicate that *looping should continue until interrupted*

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to likely set the Clip's `frame position` using [Clip#setFramePosition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#setFramePosition-int-) to 0. You will want to call this before `Clip#start`. You also need to check if the `LineEvent` type is the value [LineEvent.Type#STOP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineEvent.Type.html#STOP) to ensure the event is an update event or close, and it is indeed when it stops.

```java
@Override
public void update(LineEvent event) {
    try {
        if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e)  {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```